# Is there a way to make a custom about blank page?

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I'm currently working on my website and I had kept some placeholder links in it without linking it to any place, once open I get to the webpage **about:blank#blocked** , I was wondering if I could replace the blank screen and add a custom page maybe with .htaccess

http://rhysjosmin.tk/Subpages/Ongoing%20Projects/Ongoing.html
[The link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REQUx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When clicking invalid links such as `http://` the browser does not know what to do and redirects you to some browser specific error page. Your server will not get any requests relating to this action.

I would suggest you replace all placeholder links with a valid link, let's say http://rhysjosmin.tk/Subpages/Placeholder.html, and create your custom page there.

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense, ill do that, but i want it to just be there like how if you go to a wrong page and you get a 404 page like this [link](http://rhysjosmin.tk/blobadedajokd)

Comment: Be where? If you've set up a 404 page for your root directory with .htaccess you can do the same for the Subpages directory by placing a similar .htaccess file in it linking to another HTML file.